# stack install cause error "cannot satisfy -package-id ..."

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, wreq

I'm using the latest Haskell Platform 8.2.2 on my MacOS El Captain.

When I create a new project and install `wreq`, I will get the following error

```
stack new hello
cd hello
stack build // <- this is fine
stack install wreq // <- this command will cause the following error after a few seconds
```

---

```
▸ stack install wreq
asn1-encoding-0.9.5: configure
asn1-encoding-0.9.5: build
cryptohash-0.11.9: configure
cryptohash-0.11.9: build
data-default-0.7.1.1: configure
data-default-0.7.1.1: build
blaze-builder-0.4.0.2: configure
data-default-0.7.1.1: copy/register
asn1-encoding-0.9.5: copy/register
blaze-builder-0.4.0.2: build
exceptions-0.8.3: configure
exceptions-0.8.3: build
cryptohash-0.11.9: copy/register
Progress: 5/46
--  While building custom Setup.hs for package exceptions-0.8.3 using:
      /Users/leo/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /Users/leo/zhangchiqing/hello/.stack-work/logs/exceptions-0.8.3.log

    Configuring exceptions-0.8.3...
    Preprocessing library for exceptions-0.8.3..
    Building library for exceptions-0.8.3..
    <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id stm-2.4.4.1-6AExGOUG8NB2Rzejnay0ww
        (use -v for more information)


--  While building custom Setup.hs for package blaze-builder-0.4.0.2 using:
      /Users/leo/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /Users/leo/zhangchiqing/hello/.stack-work/logs/blaze-builder-0.4.0.2.log

    Configuring blaze-builder-0.4.0.2...
    Preprocessing library for blaze-builder-0.4.0.2..
    Building library for blaze-builder-0.4.0.2..
    <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id text-1.2.2.2-EakMpasry3jA6OIwSZhq9M
        (use -v for more information)
```

My environment:

```
▸ stack --version
Version 1.6.1, Git revision f25811329bbc40b0c21053a8160c56f923e1201b (5435 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.20.0

▸ cabal --version
cabal-install version 2.0.0.1
compiled using version 2.0.1.1 of the Cabal library

▸ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.2.2
```

Comment: Which stackage snapshot? Check your `stack.yaml`.

Comment: The default one: resolver: lts-10.2

Comment: Works on my system... got the log files mentioned?

Comment: The log only contains no message other than what I posted
I force uninstalled the haskell platform. and reinstalled with home-brew, and did stack upgrade, then works. 
Thanks for looking into this anyway.